# Session unset unsetting every variable?

Tags: php, session

I only want to unset play_mode however the second line also unsets landing_site.

Why is this happening?

```
session_start();

session_unset($_SESSION['play_mode']);

echo $_SESSION['landing_site'];
```

Comment: if I change the third line for a simple ECHO I get: "" if I remove the second line I get "www.example.com"...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because, as per [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-unset.php),

```
The session_unset() function frees all session variables currently registered.
```

Also, `session_unset()` takes no arguments.

If you only want to unset `$_SESSION['play_mode']`, then just do `unset($_SESSION['play_mode'])`.

Answer (score 1):

[session_unset](http://pl2.php.net/manual/en/function.session-unset.php)
`The session_unset() function frees all session variables currently registered.`
Try this instead:

```
unset($_SESSION['play_mode']);
```

[edit]
This question needs more people linking the manual!

Answer (score 1):

From php.net

```
void session_unset ( void )
The session_unset() function frees all session variables currently registered.
```

If you want to unset just one variable then just use unset.

```
unset($_SESSION['play_mode']);
```

Answer (score 0):

you want unset() for a single var not session_unset() the whole session